# How to make my branch be identical to its correspondent remote branch ?

Tags: git

This post follows my previous post about git pull: [Git: What does EXACTLY "git pull" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137769/git-what-does-exactly-git-pull-do/45138435#45138435)

Let's say that I want to do "git pull" to a certain branch and I want that my local copy of this branch will be IDENTICAL to the remote copy of the remote one. How to do it?

Comment: fast way: remove your local branch and pull it again

Comment: Or `git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Of course do this after first fetching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're already on the branch in question (and it's tracking the upstream correctly), the simplest way is

```
git fetch && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

This uses the special `FETCH_HEAD` ref so you don't need to type the upstream branch name or anything else.

Comment: you seem to be very useful

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/{insert branch name}
git clean -fd
```

If you want it to really be the same including removing the gitignored stuff, use `git clean -fdx`.

Comment: It doesn't do the job in all cases. Maybe the result of the pull is the the local version and not the remote one.
It should be "git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>"

Answer (score 1):

Git pull always does two things.

```
1) fetches the remote repository
2) either makes a rebase or a merge
```

So the best option to drop your local changes is doing a fetch, then a reset your local *branch* to the origin/*branch*

Answer (score 0):

After fetching with `git fetch`, `git reset @{u}` will set a branch to point to its upstream. `git reset --hard @{u}` will additionally check that revision out, **permanently discarding any changes to tracked files in your working directory**.

If you want to also discard untracked files, that can be done in bash as follows:

```
bash -c '
  GLOBIGNORE=.:..
  shopt -s dotglob extglob
  rm -rf !(.git)
  git reset --hard @{u}'
```

Comment: when you say "upstream branch" you mean the correspondent branch in remote repository ?

Comment: What is  @{u} ? Is it branch name?

Comment: @CrazySynthax: I mean [“upstream”](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/advanced-git-concepts-the-upstream-tracking-branch/).