# How to use Git pull on file that is updated by 2 or more users

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Lets say you are working on a project with someone else. You both have updated version of your project. There is a file called "example.cpp". Both of you work on that same file simultaneously and make multiple changes on your local system. One of you push the changes to git. Now when the other pulls the changes, wouldn't that overwrite everything you have done in that file on your system?

I have been basically making another copy of the git directory and doing my work there because I don't know what git pull would do to the work I have done so far. I need some clarification please.

Comment: What you described will typically cause a 'conflict' which needs to be resolved. And during a 'conflict' git will maintain both changes for you, and you can choose to accept either or both or none, or just edit your own version and then commit and push back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: What does EXACTLY "git pull" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137769/git-what-does-exactly-git-pull-do)

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky until you realize that Git isn't actually about *files*.  Git is about *commits*.

Commits *store* files.  Inside each commit, Git stores a full and complete copy of *all* of your files.  That's not all of a commit—the files are its data, and a commit holds *metadata* as well, such as information about who made the commit (name and email address), when (date-and-time-stamp), and why (the log message they wrote when they made the commit).  There's even more to it than that, but we won't get into that in this answer.

The thing to remember is this: Git stores *commits*, and each one of those commits stores *every* file.  Once you—or anyone—make a commit, *nothing about that commit can ever be changed*.  So as long as you still have any one particular commit you made, you still have *all* of the files, as of the way they were when you made that one commit.  All commits are always, 100%, totally read-only.  Most commits remain in your repository forever.

(It's a bit hard, but definitely not impossible, to get rid of a commit.  Don't worry too much about "bad" commits taking up a lot of space.  The frozen-for-all-time snapshots of every file are compressed—often highly compressed—and thus usually take far less space than the original files, *and*, since they're frozen forever, Git can and does *re-use* them automatically.  That is, suppose you make 100 commits in a row, changing only one file each time.  This can be the same file each time, or a different one each time, and you can change it back and forth if you like—it doesn't really matter.  Let's say there are 500 files in each of these 100 commits.  Since only one file is different in your *next* commit, it re-uses 499 files from the previous commit!  And, if you change a file *back*, the new file is the same as the old copy in an old commit, and Git automatically just re-uses the old copy.)

Each commit has a big ugly hash ID that is unique to that one particular commit.  The magic of this hash ID is that it is not only unique to *that* commit, but also, *every Git in the universe* will agree that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID.  No other commit anywhere gets that ID.<sup>1</sup>  So it's easy for two Gits to tell whether they have the same commits or not: they just look at each other's hash IDs.  (Actually *getting* the commit requires getting any files they have that you don't, too, but it's quick to check whether you already have it.)

With that in mind, here's the answer:

- First, we should note this: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then—if that works—run a second Git command, typically `git merge`*.
- The `git fetch` command has your Git call up someone else's Git, and ask them for any commits they have, that you don't have, that your Git should get.  They give you those commits, and now you have your commits *plus* their commits.  This does nothing to any of your commits, so it's always completely safe.
- The `git merge` command is not quite as safe—but it's pretty safe!  It first checks to make sure that you've committed *your* work.  If not, it complains and makes you commit it ... and once you have, *all* of your files, as of the state they have when you commit them, are safely frozen for all time in your new commit.
- The `git merge` operation works by finding changes.  You and your friend / co-worker started with some *common* commit—some commit with the same hash ID, that you and they got by sharing, earlier.  Then you made some changes to some files and made a new snapshot that saved your changes—in the form of the new whole files—forever, and *they* also made some changes and made a new snapshot that saved their changes forever.  Merge compares the *merge base* commit—the one you both started with—to your own latest commit, and separately, to his latest commit.

Comparing any two commits tells you what is *different* in those two commits.  So now Git knows what you changed, and also what they changed.  The merge operation *combines* these changes, and applies the combined changes to the snapshot from the base version.

If you and they changed the *same* lines of the *same* files, you will get what Git calls a *merge conflict*.  In this case, Git leaves you with a mess, and you must clean it up manually, perhaps with the help of a *merge tool*.  But if Git thinks it is able to combine your changes on its own, Git will go ahead and commit the resulting combined-changes snapshot, as a *merge commit*.  This merge commit remembers the hash IDs of both your own immediately-preceding commit *and* their last commit, so that Git knows which two commits went into performing the merge, and can show you both "legs" of the history that result from this merge.

Some people might advise you to use `git stash` before `git pull`, rather than making your own commit.  You *can* do this, but I don't recommend it.  The reason is simple enough: all `git stash push`<sup>2</sup> does is make some commits that are not on *any* branch.  This makes the `git pull` easier, because now you don't have a commit to merge when `git pull` does its fetch-and-merge step—it merges using the commits on the *branch*—but afterward you'll need to use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` to *undo* the stash.

You might forget to do this right away, and start by making some changes that you have not committed, then remember the `git stash apply` / `git stash pop` step.  This operation uses the commits that `git stash push` made to run a *much less safe* version of `git merge`.  If things go badly here, it can be very hard to recover the stuff you changed but didn't commit.  So by using `git stash`, you're just putting off the merge that you'll need to do anyway.

Once you know lots about merging and other Git operations, you can use `git stash push`, `git stash apply`, and `git stash drop` more safely, but while you are a Git newbie, I recommend avoiding it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, two different Git repositories can re-use a hash ID as long as you never introduce those two Git repositories to each other.  For more about this, see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>What is now spelled `git stash push` was spelled `git stash save` in older versions of Git.  The new spelling, `push`, fixes a bunch of minor issues with options and allows some new features, and also helps explain why `pop` is sort of the counterpart of `push`.  The problem I have with `git stash pop`—well, aside from my overall objections to using `git stash` very much in the first place —is that Git will drop the stash if *Git* thinks the apply step went well.  Sometimes the apply step goes badly even though Git thinks it was fine, or you've applied the wrong stash, and it would be nice to *not* have dropped the stash.

(If you make a lot of stashes, you'll find that sometimes they are very hard to tell apart.  After a while you don't know which ones you are keeping for what reason.  Admittedly [commits can have the same problem](https://xkcd.com/1296/), but at least here, you have more of a chance of figuring things out again later.)

Answer (score 1):

git pull syncs with the remote repository for any changes.

https://guide.freecodecamp.org/miscellaneous/git-pull-vs-git-fetch/

What you can do to save your uncommitted files is to use `git stash` command then `git pull` then `git stash pop`. If there are any conflicts to what you have, now's your chance to edit it :)

more info on stash can be found here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Answer (score 1):

So, you should merge it. 
It's normal situation. If you beginner in git please use something like GitExtensions or SourceTree (it will be better for beginers), or TortoiseGit.

The system will offer you to solve this conflicts. It will open windows that will splited to 2-3 parts. You will see changes from one branch and from another. For each conflict you should choose what code will saved as result. In the bottom placed resulted file. 
[image]

Some theory if you will interesting in it. There are 2 instances of your branch (as example I will use branch name "master"):

1. master(your local version of branch)
2. origin\master(version of branch that stored in the serve).

If somebody push code to master, then origin\master will differ from your master and you should merge it

But it's bad practise when 2 persons work in one branch. When you pull branch and start to merge then you can overwrite your changes (Due to lack of experience) and lose it.

If you beginner please work in separated branches and push\pull it without merge. And create merge commits to master when you need. It will give you posibiliti to rollback. 
If somthing was wrong you can cancel changes and reset branches to server version.

Answer (score 0):

```
** You can manage this by different ways such as **
```

1. **By creating a common branch where everyone will push updates and next you should pull the branch every time before start work and merge the file**
2. and you can normally fetch the files and merge with the bottom branch (bottom branch name is the last updated branch) that hold the latest updates